# Postgres skip update if NEW equals OLD without triggers

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Let's say I have a table I need to update with a mixture of new, changed and unchanged existing data (for legacy reasons we cannot separate them into 3 different calls).

The minimal example table is this:

```
(
    id        integer,
    name      text
        constraint name_unique
            unique,
    metadata  jsonb,
    version   integer default 0
);
```

There are 3 different things that need to happen:

1. Insert the new values if `name` is not there (`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT (name) ...`)
2. Update `metadata` and bump `version` with `1` if `name` is already there and `OLD.metadata <> NEW.metadata` <- this is the one I cannot write down with the `ON CONFLICT` syntax as it only(?) gives me access to `NEW` value as `EXCLUDED` but not the value at hand in `ROW`.
3. Skip update and version bump if `OLD.metadata = NEW.metadata`

My current best guess was casting `jsonb` to plain text and see if the two was the same, but I could not figure out if it was possible to do it without having to write a `FUNCTION` and a `TRIGGER`.

**Can these 3 things performed in one query?**

Comment: There is no `EXCLUDED` in your query. (in fact: there is no query at all!)

Comment: @wildplasser I started preparing the last not working version (it was updating other things as well) then I had a jolt of idea. I think now I have rubber ducked it. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference the new row version with `EXCLUDED` in the `ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE` clause:

```
INSERT INTO tab (name, metadata)
VALUES ('obadja', '{"silly": 42}')
ON CONFLICT ON name_unique
DO UPDATE SET metadata = EXCLUDED.metadata,
              version = tab.version + 1
WHERE tab.metadata IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.metadata;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved this problem.

```sql
INSERT
INTO example (id, name, metadata, version)
VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Random', '{}', DEFAULT)
on conflict(name) do
    update set
               metadata = excluded.metadata,
               version = example.version + 1
where
        example.name = excluded.name and
        cast(example.metadata as text) <> cast(excluded.metadata as text);
```

Let me know if I made any mistakes.